# Android FirebaseMessaging - getToken fails for some users

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

I have the following setup in my grade files:

project:

```
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.10'
        classpath 'com.google.firebase:firebase-crashlytics-gradle:2.8.1'
```

app:

```
    implementation platform('com.google.firebase:firebase-bom:29.0.0')

    // When using the BoM, you don't specify versions in Firebase library dependencies
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-crashlytics'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging'
```

After the users logs in, I'm doing

```
FirebaseMessaging.getInstance().getToken().addOnCompleteListener(task -> {
    String refreshToken = task.getResult();
    ....
}
```

which is fine for most users, but for some (not only a few) get errors like `FIS_AUTH_ERROR`, `MISSING_INSTANCEID_SERVICE`, `SERVICE_NOT_AVAILABLE`.

I guess (!), `MISSING_INSTANCEID_SERVICE` is no Google API on the device, `SERVICE_NOT_AVAILABLE` missing network (?) but I'm not sure at all. And I have absolutely no clue about the `FIS_AUTH_ERROR`. Is there some documentation about this?

Comment: Can you check if your API key is [permitted on Firebase Installations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72286983/android-firebasemessaging-gettoken-fails-for-some-users)?

Comment: will do; but if it’s invalid, wouldn’t it be a problem for all users?

Answer (score 1):

**MISSING_INSTANCEID_SERVICE**

Tokens can't be generated.

**SERVICE_NOT_AVAILABLE**

The device cannot read the response, or there was a server error.

**FIS_AUTH_ERROR**

you need to check the documentation get token and get id methods had changed

I think it has to do with firebase dependencies versions mismatch. Try to import the BoM for the Firebase platform. By using BoM your app will always use compatible versions of the Firebase Android libraries.

```
dependencies {
  // Import the BoM for the Firebase platform
  implementation platform('com.google.firebase:firebase-bom:30.0.2')
  // .... }
```

Comment: I don't think so, because it works for some ...

Answer (score 0):

`FIS_AUTH_ERROR` suggests, that the local installation cannot be authenticated:

> Firebase Cloud Messaging uses Firebase installation IDs to target devices for message delivery.

Source: [Manage Firebase installations](https://firebase.google.com/docs/projects/manage-installations#android)

It's a little difficult, unless having a device available, which would show this issue - or somehow being able to narrow this down - by hardware vendor, Android version or package version - because "some (not only a few)" is relatively meaningless, from a technical perspective.

It could well be, that the SHA1/SHA265 key fingerprint might have been changed (you should know) and "some (not only a few)" might still haven't updated to the latest version of the APK/AAB package, signed with the new signing key. Crashlytics would show the package version. You could add the old SHA1/SHA265 key fingerprint back in, so that their instances could authenticate again.